# How to get distinct loggers in log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

If my log4j.properties looks this

```
# General configuration
log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, ConsoleAppender

# Appender configuration
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %5p (%c) %m%n
#Other Loggers
log4j.logger.com.foo=INFO
log4j.logger.com.foo.Bar=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
```

Is there an easy way to get just the loggers `com.foo`, `com.foo.Bar`, `root`, and `org.springframework`.  And not the specific classes that have been created and inherit the levels (I.E. `com.foo.bar.Baz`?
For my purposes I want to create an admin page that displays these loggers and their levels, but not ALL loggers, just the ones that have been directly configured via properties. currently, I am traversing up the parent hierarchy until I come across a logger that has a different level that its parent, but that can hide some configured loggers if they are in the hierarchy and set the same level as something higher up.

Comment: Is parsing the properties file out of the question?

Comment: No, using log4j programaticly to discover which loggers have been configured, and are not just inheriting from other loggers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this. First get all loggers from the log manager:

```
Enumeration<Category> loggers = LogManager.getCurrentLoggers();
```

Then you can ask each logger for its level:

```
Level currentLevel = logger.getLevel();
```

`currentLevel` will be `null` if it has never been explicitly set. So, if the logger was set to a specific level in `log4j.properties`, you will get a non-null value. Else you will get a `null` value. The root logger always reports a level, so that would be a special case. This way, you would not need to parse the `log4j.properties` file.

The only problem is that if somewhere in your code you invoke `setLevel()` on a logger, it will also report non-null and appear on your list. That is because log4j does not know *how* a level was set, only if it was set at all. To distinguish these two cases, you would still need to parse `log4j.properties`.

Also, keep in mind that this works only on loggers which are currently loaded. So if `com.foo.Bar` was never loaded, you will not see it on your list even if it is explicitly mentioned in `log4j.properties`. Log4J does not know about non-existing loggers which might be created in the future. Again, for this you would need to parse `log4j.properties`.

Comment: There is no getCurrentLoggers() in LogManager. Log4j 2.2.

Comment: @MagnoC Right, my answer refers to [Log4J v1](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/LogManager.html). Log4J v2 was still two years away at the time of the answer (released 2014).

Comment: Ok. I'm Just complaining... I need to wrap Log4J into my own Logger class (to preserve names I need to remove Log4J JARs and create my classes with same names) and add Log4J JARs again. So I call real logger from inside my Logger class (using complete class name). Now I can enable and disable MY logger. When disabled, I just not pass log string thru real log.